# c# is there a built-in / default delegate for same input and output type? Like a 'Transform' delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, standard-library

This is a very simple question. Should I define my own delegate:

```
public delegate T Transform<T>(T input);
```

Or is there already a standard one defined within .Net?

Comment: The closest I'm aware of is Converter delegate, but it maps potentially different input type to output type (but if you set input and output to the same type - will be your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Func<T, T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) for that. The first is the parameter, the second is the return value.  Look here [Func Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use generic `Func`, see [description from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
    T arg
)
```

Example usage:

```
Func<string, string> transformer = str => str.ToUpper();
```